# mysql not reading \N when loading from csv file and using str_to_date

Tags: mysql, date, null

The following are my table & file

```
CREATE table LOCATION
(
Place varchar(50) not null,
Date date,
CONSTRAINT location_pk PRIMARY KEY(Place)
);
```

location.txt:

```
Place   Date
School  2023-03-04
Market      \N  

LOAD DATA INFILE “/xxxx/location.txt” INTO TABLE LOCATION FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘\t’ LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\n’ IGNORE 1 LINES
(Place, date)
SET

Date=IF(date='\N', NULL, STR_TO_DATE(date, '%Y-%m-%d'));
Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: 'N' for column 'date' at row 1
```

OR

```
Date=STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y-%m-%d');
Incorrect date value: 'N ' for column 'Date' at row 24
```

OR

```
Date=NULLIF(date, '\N'),
Date=STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y-%m-%d');
Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: 'N' for column 'date' at row 1
```

I've tried using three different methods but it seems like my workbench doesn't read \N as null unless I use nullif. I also cannot edit the txt file.

What other options or functions can I use to solve this issue?

Comment: In MySQL `'\N'` is equivalent to `N`; to get the backslash inside a string literal, escape it: `'\\N'`. The same is true inside the file loaded by `LOAD DATA`: "Interpret characters preceded by the escape character `\ ` as escape sequences. For example, `\t`, `\n`, and `\\ ` signify tab, newline, and backslash, respectively. See the discussion of `FIELDS ESCAPED BY` later for the full list of escape sequences."

Comment: Try `LOAD DATA ... FIELDS ESCAPED BY ''` (empty string) to turn off the escape mechanism.

Comment: it still doesn't work. It just adds the backslash '\N' in the same error 1292 for row 1. I've tried adding an additional slash or using escaped by.

Comment: There are two problems: your code has `'\N'` which is misinterpreted (try `SELECT '\N'` vs `SELECT '\\N'` to see what happens); and your file has `\N` that is misinterpreted. You need to fix both; the first by writing `'\\N'` in your code, the second by preventing `LOAD DATA` escaping. If you are getting "Incorrect date value: '\N' for column 'date' at row 1" (with backslash), that means the file has been read correctly, but `IF` (or `NULLIF`) failed to detect `\N`.

Comment: @Amadan it still shows "Incorrect date value: '\N' for column 'date' at row 1" after both fixes, what do I do? My other tables that use nullif(attribute, '\N') works perfectly fine

Comment: Review Input Preprocessing section in the manual - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html note the use of user defined variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using input preprocessing [dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) and testing the first character in @date

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;

CREATE table T
(
Place varchar(50) not null,
Date  date ,
CONSTRAINT location_pk PRIMARY KEY(Place)
);

LOAD DATA INFILE  'inputfile' INTO TABLE T 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(Place, @date)
SET 
Date=case when left(@date,1) <> '2'  then null else @date end
;
SELECT * FROM T;

+--------+------------+
| Place  | Date       |
+--------+------------+
| Market | NULL       |
| School | 2023-03-04 |
+--------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

note the implicit conversion of @date to date

left 1 may be too simple for your needs but you get the idea...

Comment: Thank you it works! Do you mind explaining this line "Date=case when left(@date,1) <> '2' "

Comment: Not sure what your last comment is about specifically, in general all sql commands are available in input reprocessing so maybe you are curious about the <> clause ? In the case of \N the \ is stripped before the test so a simple test will do.